# Access Crosstab Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, crosstab

The select query works perfectly (access 2013). As soon as I change it to a crosstab it gives me the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." I am using a vba function in the crosstab value as an expression. I have no null values in my table and have tried using variant as my data type.

VBA

```
enter code here
'assumes that the rate is monthly
Public Function payFrequency(frequency As String, rate As Currency) As Currency
If frequency = "BI-WEEKLY" Then
    payFrequency = rate * 12 / 26
    Exit Function
ElseIf frequency = "SEMI-MONTHLY" Then
    payFrequency = rate * 12 / 24
    Exit Function
ElseIf frequency = "MONTHLY" Then
    payFrequency = rate
    Exit Function
Else
    payFrequency = 0
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

and the SQL

```
TRANSFORM 
  payfrequency([structurepayrollFrequency],
  Max([2015_PREMIUM]-[2015_EMPLOYER_CONTR])) AS 2015_EMPLOYEE_CONTR
```

Comment: I wonder what happens if, instead of VBA, you build this function in the query.  That would be my preferred solution in any case; VBA calls from a query are often not efficient, and can be harder to trouble shoot.

Comment: That worked! Thank you Smandoli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of VBA, I suggest you build this function in the query. That would be my preferred solution in any case; VBA calls from a query are often not efficient, and can be harder to trouble shoot.